# What network protocols does luarocks install use?

Tags: luarocks

I am running on a redhat box, behind a corporate firewall.  I'm guessing that some of the protocols are getting blocked, but I'm a relative neophyte to git, and this is my first time ever using luarocks.  It looks to me like luarocks is trying to use https:// so there should be no firewall issues....  But the error messages imply a firewall problem.

Here's what I know:

I do know that this git command works fine on my machine.  git is able to clone the repository locally, and I can build luarocks from source.

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/luajit-rocks.git
```

But, this command fails:

```
luarocks install cwrap
```

Here is the output from the command

```
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/luarocks_cwrap-scm-1-8589/cwrap/.git/
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaRocks uses LuaSocket and LuaSec when available to do HTTP and HTTPS, but apart from that it just defers to external commands, such as `git`.
You can run `luarocks` with the `--verbose` flag and it will output every external command it calls. You can then check what is the `git` command line it is calling, and try it directly from the command line. This should help to diagnose if any flag is causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can force git to use https with the following command:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Source: https://github.com/torch/rocks/issues/38